# Possible to reuse my GCancellable instance?

Tags: c, gtk3, glib, gdbus

Before triggering a proxy-call via gdbus, I want to cancel any possible pending calls on this dbus method. My first attempt was like that:

```
// in the "member" list of my widget
GCancellable   *my_cancellable;

// in the init method of my widget:
plugin->my_cancellable = g_cancellable_new ();

// in the method which does the call
g_cancellable_cancel (plugin->my_cancellable);
my_gdbus_call_something (plugin->proxy, plugin->my_cancellable, reply_handler,plugin);
```

That did not work out, since using the same cancellable instance as well will cancel any future call.
Looks like I cannot use [g_cancellable_reset](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GCancellable.html#g-cancellable-reset), since the doc stats the following:

> If cancellable is currently in use by any cancellable operation then
>   the behavior of this function is undefined.

Is it possible to check the in-use state of my GCancellable? Would it help me at all ?

What already works fine for me is to create a new cancellable for each call:

```
// in the "member" list of my widget
GCancellable   *my_cancellable;

// in the init method of my widget:
plugin->my_cancellable = NULL;

// in the method which does the call
if(plugin->my_cancellable != NULL)
  {
    g_cancellable_cancel (plugin->my_cancellable);
    g_object_unref (plugin->my_cancellable);
  }
plugin->my_cancellable = g_cancellable_new ();
my_gdbus_call_something (plugin->proxy, plugin->my_cancellable, reply_handler,plugin);
```

Is it save to unref my_cancellable, considered there is a pending call ? This must be a standard use-case .. I wonder if there is no better solution.

Comment: Do you know why you added the tag for `objective-c`? It is another language and so it appears unrelated to me.

Comment: I think you generally don't want to reuse cancellables for multiple operations. Is there a reason you need to keep a reference to it in your struct?

Comment: What about cancel it first, then reset it and reuse it afterwards?

Comment: @ptomato ok for me to just dont reuse. I have the cancellables in my struct because I want to cancel all pending operations on finalize, when my widget gets destroyed.

Comment: @Jose Fonte I'll have a try. So directly after calling cancel, reset should be safe?

Comment: Like you said, resetting a cancellable in use is undefined but if you cancel it first, then it's not in use and you should be able to reset it for reuse.

Comment: Thanks José Fonte! Seems to work fine now .. I just did not know that a cancellable is not "in use" any more, when it is cancelled.

Comment: Feel free to complete your question with your own answer to "close it" and serve as reference to future readers. GL

Comment: I first waited if you would do, than I forgot about this question :) Thanks for the offer! Answer added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first coding attempt was almost fine .. I just did not realize that a cancellable is not "in use" any more, when it is cancelled, so after calling [g_cancellable_cancel](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GCancellable.html#g-cancellable-cancel) it is safe to call [g_cancellable_reset](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GCancellable.html#g-cancellable-reset)

Thanks to José Fonte for pointing that out!

Here the fixed code:

```
// in the "member" list of my widget
GCancellable   *my_cancellable;

// in the init method of my widget:
plugin->my_cancellable = g_cancellable_new ();

// in the method which does the call
g_cancellable_cancel (plugin->my_cancellable);
g_cancellable_reset (plugin->my_cancellable);
my_gdbus_call_something (plugin->proxy, plugin->my_cancellable, reply_handler,plugin);
```